# When to use decimals or doubles

Tags: sql, .net, double, decimal, precision

Quick Aside: I'm going to use the word "Float" to refer to both a .Net float and a SQL float with only 7 significant digits. I will use the word "Double" to refer to a .Net double and a SQL float with 15 significant digits. I also realize that this is very similar to some other posts regarding decimals/doubles, but the answers on those posts are really inconsistent, and I really want some recommendations for my specific circumstance...

I am part of a team that is rewriting an old application. The original app used floats (7 digits). This of course caused issues since the app conducted a lot of calculations and rounding errors accumulated very quickly. At some point, many of these floats were changed to decimals. Later, the floats (7) in the database all became doubles (15). After that we had several more errors with calculations involving doubles, and they too were changed to decimals.

Today about 1/3 of all of our floating point numbers in the database are decimals, the rest are doubles. My team wants to "standardize" all of our floating-point numbers in the database (and the new .Net code) to use either exclusively decimals or doubles except in cases where the other MUST be used. The majority of the team is set on using decimals; I'm the only person on my team advocating using doubles instead of decimals. Here's why...

1. Most of the numbers in the database are still doubles (though much of the application code still uses floats), and it would be a lot more effort to change all of the floats/doubles to decimals
2. For our app, none of the fields stored are "exact" decimal quantities. None of them are monetary quantities, and most represent some sort of "natural" measurement (e.g. mass, length, volume, etc.), so a double's 16 significant digits are already way more precise than even our initial measurements.
3. Many tables have measurements stored in two columns: 1 for the value; 1 for the unit of measure. This can lead to a HUGE difference in scale between the values in a single column. For example, one column can store a value in terms of pCi/g or Ci/m3 (1 Ci = 1000000000000 pCi). Since all the values in a single decimal columns must have the same *scale* (that is... an allocated number of digits both before and after the decimal point), I'm concerned that we will have overflow and rounding issues.

My teammates argue that:

1. Doubles are not as *accurate* nor as *precise* as decimals due to their inability to *exactly* represent 1/10 and that they *only* have 16 significant digits.
2. Even though we are not tracking money, the app is a inventory system that keeps track of material (mostly gram quantities) and it needs to be "as accurate as possible".
3. Even after the floats were changed to doubles, we continued to have bad results from calculations that used doubles. Changing these columns (and the application code) to decimals caused these calculations to produce the expected results.

It is my strong belief that the original issues where caused due to floats only having 7 significant digits and that simple arithmetic (e.g. 10001 * 10001) caused them to the data to quickly use up the few significant digits that they had. I do not believe this had anything to do with how binary-floating point numbers can only *approximate* decimal values, and I believe that using doubles would have fixed this issue.

I believe that the issue with doubles arose because doubles were used along side decimals in calculations that values were be converted back and forth between data types. Many of these calculations would round between intermediary steps in the calculation!

I'm trying to convince my team not to make everything under the sun into a decimal. Most values in the database don't have more than 5 or 6 significant digits anyway. Unfortunately, I am out-ranked by other members of my team that see things rather differently.

### So, my question then is...

1. Am I worrying over nothing? Is there any real harm done by using almost exclusively decimals instead of doubles in an application with nearly 200 database tables, hundreds of transactions, and a rewrite schedule of 5 to 6 years?
2. Is using decimals actually solving an issue that doubles could not? From my research, both decimals and doubles are susceptible to rounding errors involving arbitrary fractions (adding 1/3 for example) and that the only way to account for this is to consider any value within a certain tolerance as being "equal" when comparing doubles and/or decimals.
3. If it is more appropriate to use doubles, what arguments could I make (other than what I have already made) could convince my team to not change *everything* to decimals?

Comment: What kind of calculations are being performed on the numbers? If they're limited to strictly rational operations then you should consider storing numbers as integer-pairs (of numerator and denominators), that way there will be no rounding errors at all.

Comment: A typically calculation may involve the radioactivity of a certain quantity of material. The amount of material present and what units the user wishes to see the result (pCi/g, Ci/m3, or MBq/l). If the result needs to be expressed in terms involving volume, then we also have to include calculations involving how many grams there are, and the size of the container.

Comment: Those look like normal arithmetic operations to me - provided you don't use any one-way functions or irrational values (like `Sqrt`) you should be fine moving to an internal rational representation system.

Comment: @NuclearProgrammer, your question was worded very well. I happen to have the same query, would you be alright in sharing your findings since, i.e. what did you eventually agree on.

Answer (score 1):

Use `decimal` when you need perfect accuracy as a base-10 number (financial data, grades)

Use `double` or `float` when you are storing naturally imprecise data (measurements, temperature), want *much* faster mathematical operations, and can sacrifice a minute amount of imprecision.

Since you seem to be only storing various measurements (which have some precision anyways), `float` would be the logical choice (or `double` if you need more than 7 digits of precision).

> Is using decimals actually solving an issue that doubles could not?

Not really - The data is only going to be as accurate as the measurements used to generate the data.  Can you really say that a measured quantity is 123.4567 grams?  Does the equipment used to measure it have that level of precision?

To deal with "rounding errors" I would argue that you can't really say whether a measurement of 1234.5 grams is *exactly* halfway - it could just as easily be 1234.49 grams, which would round down anyways.

What you need to decide is "what level of precision is acceptable" and always round to that precision *as a last step*. Don't round your data or intermediate calculations.

> If it is more appropriate to use doubles, what arguments could I make (other than what I have already made) could convince my team to not change everything to decimals?

Other than the time spent switching, the only thing you're really sacrificing is speed. The only way to know *how much speed* is to try it both ways and measure the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better try your best not to lose precision. I guess my fault may convince you to choose double.

===> I did some wrong arithmetic, and it returns something very weird:
**given `0.60`, it returns `5`**

```
int get_index(double value) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 1.00)
        return -1;
    return value / 0.10;
}
```

and I fixed it:

```
int get_index(double value) {
    if (value < 0 || value > 1.00)
        return -1;
    return (value * 100000000) / (0.10 * 100000000);
}
```